# pthread_kill kills not just a thread but the whole program

Tags: linux, pthreads, kill, sigkill

I am using `int s=pthread_kill(thread_arr[t], 9);` to send the SIGKILL signal to the thread that is in the t place of thread_arr, but instead of killing this exact thread my whole program is being killed. Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is in the man page for `pthread_kill`:

> Signal dispositions are process-wide: if a signal handler is
>   installed, the handler will be invoked in the thread, but if
>   the disposition of the signal is "stop", "continue", or "terminate",
>   this action will affect the whole process.

The disposition of SIGKILL is to terminate the process, and the signal can't be caught, blocked or ignored.

I would suggest using a different signal, and having the thread receiving the signal stop itself, instead of using

Comment: I also used other signals after your answer, but most of them kill the whole process, too. Can you please give me an example of what you are suggesting? I am new with threads and I am having a hard time understanding them.

Comment: An example is probably too long to explain here. You should look at tutorials or documentation on signal handling. There is a short one [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html).

Comment: to which thread (is it main parent thread) you are sending signal? what is your method of sending singal? programmatically or using control+C on terminal?

Comment: Where to send the signal depends on what you want to achieve and your context. If, for example, you want to send a signal to your application to for it to reconfigure, this signal can be directed to the application. If you want a specific thread to stop, you should send the signal to the thread, unless the application has a way of identifying the thread.

In these cases, I usually use the [kill](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/kill1.html) command.

Comment: Finally I opened a new process with posix_spawn running in a thread and when it was necessary I killed it with the process id using `int kill(pid,9)`. Thank you all for your answers.